# Convert fraction to decimal

Tags: sql, oracle

Working on 10g.

I am writing a query to sort a list, and sorting is an important aspect of the list.

I have already isolated the fraction from the mixed number.

I have data that come in fraction form. (3/4, 5/8, 1/2)

I need to convert them to decimal to be able to 'order by' with them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is `3/4` a string value?

Comment: if it's a string you can split on the / then cast each side then just divide the left by the right...

Comment: yes, it is a string value.

Answer (score 1):

This will blow up badly if the input is *not* a fraction such as 3/4, 5/8, etc., but here goes:

```
CAST(SUBSTR(theFraction, 1, INSTR(theFraction, '/')-1) AS NUMBER) /
CAST(SUBSTR(theFraction, INSTR(theFraction, '/')+1) AS NUMBER)
```

The logic is basically "get everything before the '/' and convert it to a number, then divide it by everything after the '/' converted as a number".